# TextView blocking ListView onItemClickListener

Tags: android-listview

I have simple list view with list items defined by following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemTextView"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

> </RelativeLayout>
```

When I click `TextView` the `listView.onItemClickListener` is not called. The problem occurs on Android 4. Android 2.x is OK. Is there any trick to pass an event from `TextView` to its `ListView` without defining `onClickListner` on the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity just make you listview as focusable true. This worked for me. If you are using a custom list view the focus is passed to its childs and not the list so to get the focus back to listview use
listView.focusable(true); 
and the other things as textview just set their focus as false.

Answer (score 0):

It was the android:textIsSelectable="true" attribute. Don't follow lint hints blindly.

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="textMultiLine"` can also cause this problem. If you've included that attribute in your `TextView` xml, try removing it.